ELSA Multitenancy where each tenant has thier own Database
Can a multitenant application, with each tenant having its own database, utilize different databases for persisting workflow instances? In our hybrid application, each tenant has a dedicated database. When a Workflow request is received, can the middleware pipeline inject the connection string into the request? Our intention is to create a scope object for IWorkflowStateStore, ITriggerStore, and IBookmarkStore. Is it possible to implement multitenancy for elsa-workflow using this approach?
Would like to use Dapper workflow provider for database persistence. The workflow will be authored using code and persisted to the database.
Also want to check to achieve multitenancy using the default packages is there a possibility  to dynamically inject the dapper.DbConnectionProvider at runtime using a scoped object which can connect to the tenant workflow database?
